# javascript get and use an input value

Tags: javascript

hello i was just wondering if there is anyway to get an input value to change / use it for the healLevel = 70% i give it a try but i'm new to this and fail.

```js
(function() {
  var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("cb1");
  var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("cb2");

  heal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-shop-item')[10];
  petHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-shop-item')[11];
  useHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-toolbar-item')[4];
  usePetHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-toolbar-item')[5];
  healthBar = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-health-bar-inner')[0];
  up = new Event('mouseup');
  healLevel = 70;

  HEAL1 = function() {
    if (checkbox1.checked) {
      heal.attributes.class.value = 'hud-shop-item';
      useHeal.dispatchEvent(up);
      heal.click();
    }
  };

  HEAL2 = function() {
    if (checkbox2.checked) {
      petHeal.attributes.class.value = 'hud-shop-item';
      usePetHeal.dispatchEvent(up);
      petHeal.click();
    }
  };

  script = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 82) {
      HEAL1();
      HEAL2();
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    script(e);
  });
  observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      if (parseInt(mutations[0].target.style.width) < healLevel) {
        HEAL1();
        HEAL2();
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(healthBar, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="70">
```

this is what i have tried this but didn't seen to work any ideas why i failed ?
i tried using document.querySelector what am i doing wrong?

```js
(function() {
  var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("cb1");
  var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("cb2");
  var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');

  heal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-shop-item')[10];
  petHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-shop-item')[11];
  useHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-toolbar-item')[4];
  usePetHeal = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-toolbar-item')[5];
  healthBar = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-health-bar-inner')[0];
  up = new Event('mouseup');
  healLevel = elem.value;
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="70">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="70" id="healRate" onchange="updateHealLevel()">
```

**JS**

```
var healLevel = document.getElementById("healRate").value;

function updateHealLevel(){
healLevel = document.getElementById("healRate").value;
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated so that a change to the input value will update the healLevel.

To have the value change with the input, you must simply add an onchange event on the HTML component so that when the user changes this input, it will run the code which will update the healLevel.

Comment: works but it don't update if i change the value in the input ?
btw thank you for the help !

Comment: @crowfish I've updated my answer and this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much this is just want i needed! and works

Comment: @crowfish No bother at all, glad this helped!